# Express binary value with specific length

Tags: python

I want to express each binary number in 4 bits. So 
bin(7) should be '0b0111' not '0b111'. How this is possible in Python? 
After that how can I extract first two bits which is '01' in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `str.format`:

```
>>> "{:04b}".format(7)
'0111'
```

if you really need the prefix:

```
>>> "0b{:04b}".format(7)
'0b0111'
```

to get first bits as string use slicing:

```
"{:04b}".format(7)[:2]
```

or shift before to keep only highest bits:

```
"{:02}".format(7 >> 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `format`

```
>>>format(7, '#06b')
'0b0111'
```

For getting the first two bits, you can

```
>>>format(7, '#06b')[2:4]
'01'
```